Tensoring with Exact C*-algebra Preserves Pullback?
My question concerns Theorem 3.9 of “Pullback and Pushout Constructions in C*-Algebra Theory” (https://doi.org/10.1006/jfan.1999.3456) by G. K. Pedersen.
Consider the following pullback diagram of C*-algebras:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{\gamma}>> B\\
@VV{\delta}V @VV{\beta}V \\
A @>{\alpha}>> C
\end{CD}$$
Taking (minimal) tensor product with another C*-algebra $Y$ gives the following commutative diagram (where $\overline{\alpha} = \alpha \otimes \mathrm{id}_Y$ and similarly for $\overline{\beta}, \overline{\gamma}, \overline{\delta}$):
$$\begin{CD}
X\otimes Y @>{\overline{\gamma}}>> B\otimes Y\\
@VV{\overline{\delta}}V @VV{\overline{\beta}}V \\
A\otimes Y @>{\overline{\alpha}}>> C\otimes Y
\end{CD}$$
Theorem 3.9 claims that the resulting diagram is pullback when $Y$ is an exact C*-algebra. The proof is left as an exercise and I do not know how to prove this.
My attempt
As shown in Proposition 3.1, it suffices to verify the following three conditions:

$\ker \overline{\gamma} \cap \ker \overline{\delta} = 0$,
$\overline{\beta}^{-1}(\overline{\alpha}(A \otimes Y)) = \overline{\gamma}(X \otimes Y)$ and
$\overline{\delta}(\ker \overline{\gamma}) = \ker \overline{\alpha}$.

I can prove the condition 1. and condition 3 ,using the fact that the exactness of $Y$ guarantees $\ker \overline{\alpha} = (\ker \alpha) \otimes Y$ and similarly for $\overline{\gamma}$ and $\overline{\delta}$. However, I do not know how to prove condition 2.
Thank you for your help.

Not directly related to the question itself, but either I’m terribly misunderstanding something, or the paper is full of errors. Like, the claim that pullbacks of nuclear $C^\ast$-algebras are nuclear seem wrong (that would imply the intersection of two nuclear $C^\ast$-algebras in an ambient nuclear $C^\ast$-algebra is nuclear, which $C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}_2)=C(X_1)\rtimes_r\mathbb{F}_2\cap C(X_2)\rtimes_r\mathbb{F}_2\subset C(X_1\times X_2)\rtimes_r\mathbb{F}_2$, where $X_1=X_2=\partial\mathbb{F}_2$, seem to be a counterexample). Theorem 3.8 also seems self-contradictory, as, if you use the…

… pullback diagram of the intersection I just wrote down, and try to tensor with $C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}_2)$, then Theorem 3.8 would seem to imply both the minimal and maximal tensor products of two copies of $C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}_2)$ are the pullbacks, which cannot be true as $C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}2)\otimes{\text{min}}C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}_2)\neq C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}2)\otimes{\text{max}}C_r^\ast(\mathbb{F}_2) $. (And indeed, Theorem 3.8 never tried to verify condition $2$.)

Oh wait, Theorem 3.8 assumes $\alpha$ is surjective, so I guess that’s not really a counterexample. But my other points stand. The proof of Theorem 3.8 never tries to verify condition $2$, that much seems inescapable.

(Regardless, I can prove Theorem 3.9 when $Y$ is nuclear, but even that uses the equivalence of nuclearity with the existence of ccp approximation maps factoring through matrix algebras. I struggle to see how there can be an easy proof for general exact $Y$. But maybe I’m just missing something.)
